# Detect fluid grids on webpage

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, fluid-layout

Is there any way to detect if a webpage uses fluid grids? Using jquery for example.

Fluid grids definition: http://1stwebdesigner.com/fluid-grid-layout/. For example, Bootstrap's col-md-* are fluid grids.

Some websites still use fixed columns layout, others (responsive ones) use fluid grids, is there any clever way to detect which one a website is programmatically?

My first idea is to use jquery to look for sibling divs/sections whose widths are all percentages. What do you think about that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not as simple as this. one may use bootstrap but source code may still contain some fixed columns too.

Also, you should know all technologies that uses fluid grids.

You may use a chrome or firefox extension like [wappalyzer](https://wappalyzer.com/) for easily detecting the technologies used in the website. but testing all the source code using jquery seems a bit complicated.

Comment: I don't think testing technologies is a good way to go, as you said, one may use bootstrap but still use a fixed layout. Testing presence of sibling divs that have percentage widths seems better to me.